# Ajax call only works once even with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying for the last two weeks on and off to get my Ajax call to work more than once, I'm self taught and trying my best to figure things out myself, but this problem is killing me. Some people with the same problem used .on and it seemed to work for them, but I can still only get it to work once.

The idea is for a user to click a button on the page, for which they are awarded with XP.

```html
<div id="AJTestt">Ajax Test</div> 

<script>
$(document).on('click', "#AJTestt", function($id, $SkillOne, $XP) {    
    $id = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
    $SkillOne = <?php if(isset($SkillOne)) echo $SkillOne; ?>;
    $XP = 3;

        //get the input value
        $.ajax({
            url: "ax.php",
            cache: "false",
            data: {id : $id, SkillOne: $SkillOne, XP: $XP},
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success"); 
                console.log(data); 
                history.back(); //Just to remove the ax.php bit
            },
            error: function(){
                    console.log("Error"); 
                    console.log(data); 
            }
        });
        });
 </script>
```

////////
PHP code (ax.php)

```html
<?php
require_once 'resource/Database.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$SkillOne= $_POST['SkillOne'];
$XP = $_POST['XP'];
echo "$id \n"; 
echo "$SkillOne \n";
echo "$XP \n";

if($XP==1){
$SkillOne = $SkillOne +1;
}
else if($XP==2){
$SkillOne = $SkillOne +2;
}
else if($XP==3){
$SkillOne = $SkillOne +3;
}

$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET SkillOne =:SkillOne WHERE id =:id";


$statement = $db->prepare($sqlUpdate);
$statement->execute(array(':SkillOne' => $SkillOne, ':id' => $id));

echo $SkillOne;
?>
```

Everything works fine first time, the console displays (for testing purposes):
-Success
-ID
-Old Xp
-Xp to be added
-New Xp

But if I click the same button again it displays the exact same values in the console.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Kind Regards
Wings

Comment: I see where you are executing the query but you aren't doing anything with the response. You need to add something like $result = $statement->fetch();
        return $result[0]; to return the response

Comment: I feel like you are mixing up PHP and javascript code. I just wonder how it worked at least once

Comment: Can you please explain what is this `function($id, $SkillOne, $XP)`

Comment: Hi Black Mamba, I created the function like that because I'm going to reuse it multiple times for different Skills and for varying amounts of xp. I use the users id, their skill (of which there are multiple) and how much XP I want to give them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the same values from the server every time because you're passing the same values *to* the server every time:

```
$(document).on('click', "#AJTestt", function($id, $SkillOne, $XP) {    
    $id = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
    $SkillOne = <?php if(isset($SkillOne)) echo $SkillOne; ?>;
    $XP = 3;
    // ...
```

The parameters you're trying to pass to the click handler won't do anything -- click just passes an `event` object, no other parameters -- and in any case you replace them immediately with fixed values. (PHP includes are only interpreted once, on page load; they do not update in real time if the underlying data on the server changes.)

If you want the values to update, you need to store the data returned from the AJAX call (which if my extremely rusty PHP skills aren't misleading me appears to just be the contents of $SkillOne) in a variable so the new value can be passed to the server on the next call. Currently you're not doing anything with that returned value other than logging it to the console.

Here, for example, the PHP-included values are set once on load in global variables (not an ideal practice, but good enough for demonstration), which can then be updated on each ajax call:

```
var $SkillOne = <?php if(isset($SkillOne)) echo $SkillOne; ?>; // probably need an `else` here too, for a default value
var $id = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
var $XP = 3;

$(document).on('click', "#AJTestt", function() { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "ax.php",
    cache: "false",
    data: { id: $id, SkillOne: $SkillOne, XP: $XP },
    dataType: 'text',
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Success");
      $SkillOne = data; // update the $SkillOne variable with the new value
      // history.back(); // Do not do this; ajax calls do not change the history stack; you'll bump the user to the page they were on previously.
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Error");
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's as simple as this but I could be wrong.

The click function creates an `event` object and makes it available like this, so you cannot pass variables/data to the function in the way you have:

```
.on('click', '#myElement', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can pass data/a variable to the function like this (see `dataVariable`):

```
.on('click', '#myElement', dataVariable, function(event) {
    doSomethingWith(dataVaraible);
});
```

If you really need to pass data to the handler then you could put `$id`, `$SkillOne` and `$XP` in an object and give the object to the handler:

```
var data = { id: 1, skillOne: 'blah', xp: 100 };

.on('click', '#myElement', data, function(event) {
    doSomethingWith(data);
});
```

But I don't think you need to pass anything to the function, you can just use them inside anyway like this

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', "#AJTestt", function() {    
    var $id = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>,
        $SkillOne = <?php if(isset($SkillOne)) echo $SkillOne; ?>,
        $XP = 3;

        //get the input value
        $.ajax({
            url: "ax.php",
            cache: "false",
            data: {id : $id, SkillOne: $SkillOne, XP: $XP},
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success"); 
                console.log(data); 
                history.back(); //Just to remove the ax.php bit
            },
            error: function(){
                    console.log("Error"); 
                    console.log(data); 
            }
        });
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you for your time and the detailed answer, you were right with me not needing to pass anything to the function and it works using your improved way. However, the problem of not working more than once is still unfortunatley there. I think this may hint at it being a php issue? Thanks Wings

Answer (score 0):

I am going to propose you the following solution. Such solution would be based upon what I have understood of your post. Let me know if it does not adjust.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="mybutton">Press Me to gain XPs</button>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "ax.php",
            cache: "false",
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success"); 
                console.log(data); 
                history.back(); //Just to remove the ax.php bit
            },
            error: function(){
                    console.log("Error"); 
                    console.log(data); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

For the backend, I'd do this:

```
<?php

    if (! isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        return;
    }

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yourdb", 'root', 'password');
    // change according to your id type
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT user_xp FROM users WHERE id=%d", $_SESSION['id']);

    $retrieved_info = $pdo->query($sql);

    $current_xp;
    if ($retrieved_info) {
        $info = $retrieved_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $current_xp = $info[0]['user_xp'];
    }


    if ($current_xp == 1) {
        $pdo->exec("UPDATE users SET user_xp=%d WHERE id=%d", $current_xp+1, $_SESSION['id']);
    } // and so on....

    echo $current_xp;

?>
```

Let me know whether this is what you needed & it's working.